# Python Program ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python-beginner, trying to write a program to: "Corona Virus Live Updates for India – Using Python".

I am getting this error, after running the code/programe:

```
    performance.append(int(row[2]) + int(row[3]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

The Code:

```
extract_contents = lambda row: [x.text.replace('\n', '') for x in row] 
URL = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'

SHORT_HEADERS = ['SNo', 'State','Indian-Confirmed', 
                'Foreign-Confirmed','Cured','Death'] 

response = requests.get(URL).content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser') 
header = extract_contents(soup.tr.find_all('th')) 

stats = [] 
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr') 

for row in all_rows: 
    stat = extract_contents(row.find_all('td')) 
    if stat: 
        if len(stat) == 5: 
            # last row 
            stat = ['', *stat] 
            stats.append(stat) 
        elif len(stat) == 6: 
            stats.append(stat) 

stats[-1][1] = "Total Cases"

stats.remove(stats[-1]) 

#Step #3:
objects = [] 
for row in stats : 
    objects.append(row[1]) 

y_pos = np.arange(len(objects)) 



performance = []
for row in stats:
    performance.append(int(row[2]) + int(row[3])) 

table = tabulate(stats, headers=SHORT_HEADERS) 
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

just changed the line `performance.append(int(row[2]) + int(row[3]))` to `performance.append(row[2] +str(int(float(row[3]))) )`

Full Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
extract_contents = lambda row: [x.text.replace('\n', '') for x in row] 
URL = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'

SHORT_HEADERS = ['SNo', 'State','Indian-Confirmed', 'Foreign-Confirmed','Cured','Death'] 

response = requests.get(URL).content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser') 
header = extract_contents(soup.tr.find_all('th')) 

stats = [] 
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr') 

for row in all_rows: 
    stat = extract_contents(row.find_all('td')) 
    if stat: 
        if len(stat) == 5: 
            # last row 
            stat = ['', *stat] 
            stats.append(stat) 
        elif len(stat) == 6: 
            stats.append(stat) 

stats[-1][1] = "Total Cases"

stats.remove(stats[-1]) 

#Step #3:
objects = [row[1] for row in stats ] 
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects)) 
performance = [row[2] +str(int(float(row[3]))) for row in stats]
table = tabulate(stats, headers=SHORT_HEADERS) 
print(table)
```